# Convert JSON String to Pretty Print JSON output using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, pretty-print

This is the JSON string I have:

```
{"attributes":[{"nm":"ACCOUNT","lv":[{"v":{"Id":null,"State":null},"vt":"java.util.Map","cn":1}],"vt":"java.util.Map","status":"SUCCESS","lmd":13585},{"nm":"PROFILE","lv":[{"v":{"Party":null,"Ads":null},"vt":"java.util.Map","cn":2}],"vt":"java.util.Map","status":"SUCCESS","lmd":41962}]}
```

I need to convert the above JSON `String` into Pretty Print JSON Output (using Jackson), like below:

```
{
    "attributes": [
        {
            "nm": "ACCOUNT",
            "lv": [
                {
                    "v": {
                        "Id": null,
                        "State": null
                    },
                    "vt": "java.util.Map",
                    "cn": 1
                }
            ],
            "vt": "java.util.Map",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "lmd": 13585
        },
        {
            "nm": "PROFILE
            "lv": [
                {
                    "v": {
                        "Party": null,
                        "Ads": null
                    },
                    "vt": "java.util.Map",
                    "cn": 2
                }
            ],
            "vt": "java.util.Map",
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "lmd": 41962
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone provide me an example based on my example above? How to achieve this scenario? I know there are lot of examples, but I am not able to understand those properly. Any help will be appreciated with a simple example.

**Updated:**

Below is the code I am using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(jsonString));
```

But this doesn't works with the way I needed the output as mentioned above.

Here's is the POJO I am using for the above JSON:

```
public class UrlInfo implements Serializable {

    private List<Attributes> attribute;

}

class Attributes {

    private String nm;
    private List<ValueList> lv;
    private String vt;
    private String status;
    private String lmd;

}


class ValueList {
    private String vt;
    private String cn;
    private List<String> v;
}
```

Can anyone tell me whether I got the right POJO for the JSON or not?

**Updated:**

```
String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url.toString(), String.class);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Object json = mapper.readValue(result, Object.class);

String indented = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter().writeValueAsString(json);

System.out.println(indented);//This print statement show correct way I need

model.addAttribute("response", (indented));
```

Below line prints out something like this:

```
System.out.println(indented);


{
  "attributes" : [ {
    "nm" : "ACCOUNT",
    "error" : "null SYS00019CancellationException in CoreImpl fetchAttributes\n java.util.concurrent.CancellationException\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:231)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.",
    "status" : "ERROR"
  } ]
}
```

which is the way I needed to be shown. But when I add it to model like this:

```
model.addAttribute("response", (indented));
```

And then shows it out in a resultform jsp page like below:

```
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Response:</legend>
            <strong>${response}</strong><br />

    </fieldset>
```

I get something like this:

```
{ "attributes" : [ { "nm" : "ACCOUNT", "error" : "null    
SYS00019CancellationException in CoreImpl fetchAttributes\n 
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:231)\n\tat 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.", "status" : "ERROR" } ] }
```

which I don't need. I needed the way it got printed out above. Can anyone tell me why it happened this way?

Answer (score 322, accepted):

To indent any old JSON, just bind it as `Object`, like:

```
Object json = mapper.readValue(input, Object.class);
```

and then write it out with indentation:

```
String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);
```

this avoids your having to define actual POJO to map data to.

Or you can use `JsonNode` (JSON Tree) as well.

Comment: Thanks StaxMan, I guess this is working. When I print indented out I get in the way I needed. But when I use indented to add into the Model so that I can show them in resultform page. It still gets printed in two three lines. I have updated the question, maybe you will get some more idea what's happening now.

Comment: The problem is with Spring then -- I guess it expects a POJO as attribute, and not a pre-formatted String. So instead of trying to format it yourself, you'd need to tell Spring to do this. When using Jackson, it should be possible to configure it to use indentation. Although to be honest, I am not sure why you even need to indent it for response.

Comment: Hi, defaultPrettyPrintingWriter() has been deprecated. Since 1.9, use writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter() instead.

Refer: http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#defaultPrettyPrintingWriter()

Comment: For Jackson 2, use SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, as specified by Marcelo C. below

Comment: any idea how to publish the amount of written value using jackson?

Comment: @BrownyLin Please update Javadoc link in comment: http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.0/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#defaultPrettyPrintingWriter--

Answer (score 146):

The simplest and also the most compact solution (for v2.3.3):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
mapper.writeValueAsString(obj)
```

Comment: You can actually shorten that even further: ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

Answer (score 34):

[`ObjectMapper.readTree()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree-java.lang.String-) can do this in one line:

```java
mapper.readTree(json).toPrettyString();
```

Since `readTree` produces a [`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toPrettyString--), this should pretty much always produce equivalent pretty-formatted JSON, as it `JsonNode` is a direct tree representation of the underlying JSON string.

### Prior to Jackson 2.10

The [`JsonNode.toPrettyString()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toPrettyString--) method was added  in Jackson 2.10.  Prior to that, a second call to the `ObjectMapper` was needed to write the pretty formatted result:

```java
mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .writeValueAsString(mapper.readTree(json));
```

Comment: The reason I like this answer is that it doesn't do any object conversion at all other than direct mapping to JSON types.  So long as the input string is valid JSON, we know the output string will be semantically equivalent JSON.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because, as already mentioned by @M.Justin, we don't do any object conversion, which is a must, if the JSON could be anything. Why make life as hard as proposed in the other answers, when you can have it as easy as proposed in this answer...

Comment: @Akito I just simplified the answer even further, thanks to the addition of `toPrettyString()` in Jackson 2.10.

Answer (score 30):

The new way using Jackson 1.9+ is the following:

```
Object json = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(diffResponseJson, Object.class);
String indented = OBJECT_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                               .writeValueAsString(json);
```

The output will be correctly formatted!

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help if my input is a runtime created object, not another json.

Comment: @Innokenty Then skip the first line.

Comment: @muttonUp Yeah, obviously. I even have done it, I don't know why I left such a stupid comment =)

Answer (score 18):

For Jackson 1.9, We can use the following code for pretty print.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

Answer (score 17):

I think, this is the simplest technique to beautify the json data,

```
String indented = (new JSONObject(Response)).toString(4);
```

where ***Response*** is a String.

Simply pass the 4(indentSpaces) in `toString()` method.

**Note:** It works fine in the android without any library. But in java you have to use the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library.

Comment: Worth noting this is using the [JSON in Java (org.json)](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library.

Comment: In android, it can use direclty without any libraray.

Comment: ```String json = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(map);
String indentedJson = (new JSONObject(json)).toString(4);``` for some reason the second one is losing the order of keys

Comment: The current approach, unfortunately, doesn't handle list of json objects. I mean [{"id":"1"}, {"id":"2"}]

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this using bellow ways:

**1. Using Jackson**

```
    String formattedData=new ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
.writeValueAsString(YOUR_JSON_OBJECT);
```

Import bellow class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
```

It's gradle dependency is :

```
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.3'
```

**2. Using Gson from Google**

```
String formattedData=new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting()
    .create().toJson(YOUR_OBJECT);
```

Import bellow class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

It's gradle is:

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Here, you can also download correct updated version from repository.

Answer (score 4):

[This looks like it might be the answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6339454/61624).  It says it's using Spring, but I think that should still help you in your case.  Let me inline the code here so it's more convenient:

```
import java.io.FileReader;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectWriter;

public class Foo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyClass myObject = mapper.readValue(new FileReader("input.json"), MyClass.class);
    // this is Jackson 1.x API only: 
    ObjectWriter writer = mapper.defaultPrettyPrintingWriter();
    // ***IMPORTANT!!!*** for Jackson 2.x use the line below instead of the one above: 
    // ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    System.out.println(writer.writeValueAsString(myObject));
  }
}

class MyClass
{
  String one;
  String[] two;
  MyOtherClass three;

  public String getOne() {return one;}
  void setOne(String one) {this.one = one;}
  public String[] getTwo() {return two;}
  void setTwo(String[] two) {this.two = two;}
  public MyOtherClass getThree() {return three;}
  void setThree(MyOtherClass three) {this.three = three;}
}

class MyOtherClass
{
  String four;
  String[] five;

  public String getFour() {return four;}
  void setFour(String four) {this.four = four;}
  public String[] getFive() {return five;}
  void setFive(String[] five) {this.five = five;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the help. The toughest part I am having is how to model my JSON into a Class? If I get that part working, I can easily code rest of it.

Comment: Can you take a look into my POJO class that I have written from the JSON? It looks right or not?

Answer (score 3):

Since `jackson-databind:2.10` JsonNode has the [`toPrettyString()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toPrettyString--) method to easily format JSON:

```java
objectMapper
  .readTree("{}")
  .toPrettyString()
;
```

From [the docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toPrettyString--):

> `public String toPrettyString()`
>
> Alternative to [`toString()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#toString--) that will
> serialize this node using Jackson default pretty-printer.
>
> **Since:**
> 2.10

Answer (score 1):

Anyone using POJO, DDO, or response class for returning their JSON can use **spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true** in their property file. It auto-formats the response.

Answer (score 0):

If you format the string and return object like `RestApiResponse<String>`, you'll get unwanted characters like escaping etc: `\n`, `\"`. Solution is to convert your JSON-string into Jackson JsonNode object and return `RestApiResponse<JsonNode>`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = objectMapper.readTree(jsonString);
RestApiResponse<JsonNode> response = new RestApiResponse<>();
apiResponse.setData(tree);
return response;
```