# Best way to make JSON pretty in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-data-jpa, gson

I have list of objects returning like the below format (not pretty).

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Bill","lastName":"Johnson"}]
```

I would like it to show like this (pretty).

```
{
    "data":[{
        "id":1,"
        firstName":"Bill",
        "lastName":"Johnson"
        }]
}
```

This is my method signature, along with my call to the service to query the DB and the return that prints json to screen.

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ResponseData<List<NameSearchDTO>>> getInfo(@PathVariable String code, @PathVariable String idType)

ResponseData<List<NameSearchDTO>> response = new ResponseData<>();

List<NameSearchDTO> results = officeService.getByCode(code, idType); 
if (!results.isEmpty()) {
            response.setData(results);
            response.setStatus(Enum.SUCCESS.getDescription());
            response.setMessage(Enum.STATUS_SUCCESS.getDescription());
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The ResponseData Class implements Serializable.  Does this make it "true" JSON as I'm not using Jackson or any other JSON library?

How do I pass the response to the below ObjectMapper to make it pretty?

```
ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jacksonMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
```

Or do I need to create some sort of JSONHelper class?

ResponseData Class

```
public class ResponseData <E> implements Serializable{


    private E data;
    private String status;
    private String message;
    private boolean hasValidationError = false;

    public E getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(E data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean getHasValidationError(){
        return hasValidationError;
    }

    public void setHasValidationError(boolean hasValidationError){
        this.hasValidationError = hasValidationError;
    }
}
```

Comment: See [Pretty print JSON output of Spring Boot Actuator endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24503790/pretty-print-json-output-of-spring-boot-actuator-endpoints) and [Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html) Generally, you can customise your `Jackson` `ObjectMapper` but it depends what version of `Spring` do you use, configuration, libraries. `Serialisable` interface is not needed and it does not make it `true` `JSON`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder enable field visibility ANY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29807879/jackson2objectmapperbuilder-enable-field-visibility-any)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way beautify the json string is as follows using Jackson:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(yourObject)
```

Comment: @Angular_Newbie this isn't Spring specific, and you'll have to repeat it every time. A lot of duplication for nothing.

Comment: I agree.  I will attempt using your third and fourth option.  Looks like Spring magic.

Comment: @Angular_Newbie well, let me know in case you need help. As a general rule, if you're on Spring, stick to the Spring way.

Comment: @LppEdd The solution is just for beautifying Json. You can create ObjectMapper in in context once and use it across your application. I am not sure what you mean by duplication for nothing?

Answer (score 2):

You tagged `gson` so you can use this library to **display** `.json` file:

`import org.json.JSONObject`

```
val json = "{\"data\":[{\"id\":1,\"firstName\":\"Bill\",\"lastName\":\"Johnson\"}]\n"

val jsonObject = JSONObject(json)

println(jsonObject.toString(4))
```

https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 2):

You can define

- a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` (no need for Spring Boot)
- a `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` Bean
- a simple `ObjectMapper` Bean annotated with `@Primary`
- a configuration property (Spring Boot - **skip to this one for the simplest**).

---

For the first solution you need to implement the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface
(skip this one if you're on Spring Boot)

```
@Configuration
class CustomWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(final List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        final ObjectMapper mapper =
                new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder()
                        .indentOutput(true)
                        .build();

        // Or build ObjectMapper without the Spring builder, it's the same thing
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper));
    }
}
```

The key is this line

```
indentOutput(true)
```

Which actually manipulates the underlying `ObjectMapper` configuration

```
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder indentOutput(boolean indentOutput) {
    this.features.put(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, indentOutput);
    return this;
}
```

---

The second one is a bit simpler

```
@Bean
Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jackson() {
   return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().indentOutput(true);
}
```

---

The third one is even simpler, just

```
@Bean
@Primary
ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
   final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);  
   return mapper;
}
```

---

A fourth way consists only on using the configuration property

```
spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Gson's pretty printing functionality.
Being that you've tagged your question with gson, I presume that its okay if you use the library. Mkyong has a great tutorial on pretty printing [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-enable-pretty-print-json-output-gson/).

The essential line from the tutorial is:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to import a bunch of new stuff. Only what system may complain about (if any). But if you're already using Jackson, and wanted to use the mapper -> just use "readValue" or "writeValue" right?

This link explains a lot of ways to do this: [Jackson Examples](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial)

Remove your result assignment and use direct conversion with Mapper

```
ObjectMapper jacksonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jacksonMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
List<NameSearchDTO> mappedResults = mapper.readValue(officeService.getByCode(code, idType) ,new TypeReference<List<NameSearchDTO>>() {} );
```

then add that to your result return. (seems a bit clunky having that added container class, but I don't pretend to know your requirements).

```
if (!mappedResults.isEmpty()) {
            response.setData(mappedResults);
            response.setStatus(Enum.SUCCESS.getDescription());
            response.setMessage(Enum.STATUS_SUCCESS.getDescription());
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toString(int indentFactor) from JSONObject