# Gson JsonArray pretty printing

Tags: java, json, gson

Here is my example:

```
public class Obj {
    String field1;
    int field2;
    public Obj(String field1, int field2) {
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        final Obj o1 = new Obj("string1",1);
        final Obj o2 = new Obj("string2",2);

        List<Obj> list = new ArrayList<Obj>(){{
            add(o1);
            add(o2);
        }};

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(list, new TypeToken<List<Obj>>(){}.getType());
        JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
        System.out.println("1-");
        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());        

        String json = gson.toJson(o1);
        System.out.println("2-");
        System.out.println(json);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
1-
[{"field1":"string1","field2":1},{"field1":"string2","field2":2}]

2-
{
  "field1": "string1",
  "field2": 1
}
```

How can I enable pretty printing for jsonArray?

I think this is enough to explain my problem, however here is some bla bla bla bla because stackoverflow ask me more details to let me post the question.

Comment: I didn't get what do you want? Dou want to write json on console looks good?

Comment: Use a `JsonWriter` with `jsonWriter.setIndent("  ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `JsonArray::toString` doesn't provide a way to configure pretty-printing.

You may just have to deserialise it using your `Gson` instance:

```
System.out.println("3-");
System.out.println(gson.toJson(jsonArray));
```

Answer (score 2):

toString(2) respect identation spaces

```
System.out.println(json.toString(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Jackson library.

Check this post:
[Convert JSON String to Pretty Print JSON output using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515994/convert-json-string-to-pretty-print-json-output-using-jackson)

The question was really similar.

Answer (score 0):

If you have server on your project i suggest make simple index.jsp and out.println this JSON. And add this plugin to your Google Chrome  [JSON Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc)

You get pretty Print Json.