# How to Pretty-Print , JSON raw datas on Android

Tags: java, android, json, api, pretty-print

I have an API in JSON , my json datas are displayed raw on my android application , i want them to be displayed in pretty print format like this

[image: Pretty JSON Data]

Not like this

[image: JSON Raw display on Android]

This is my java code :

```
package com.example.cbmedandroid;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
@Override


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


findViewById(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override


public void onClick(View arg0) {
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);


b.setClickable(false);
new LongRunningGetIO().execute();
}

private class LongRunningGetIO extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String> {
protected String getASCIIContentFromEntity(HttpEntity entity) throws    IllegalStateException, IOException {
InputStream in = entity.getContent();


StringBuffer out = new StringBuffer();
int n = 1;
while (n>0) {
byte[] b = new byte[4096];
n =  in.read(b);


if (n>0) out.append(new String(b, 0, n));
}


return out.toString();
}


@Override


protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/horaire.json");
String text = null;
try {
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);


HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


text = getASCIIContentFromEntity(entity);


} catch (Exception e) {
return e.getLocalizedMessage();
}


return text;
}


protected void onPostExecute(String results) {
if (results!=null) {
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.my_edit);


et.setText(results);


}


Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);


b.setClickable(true);
}


}
}
```

How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: It should be noted that the Apache HTTP is deprecated. You may read on the documentation about [making HTTP requests](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a JSON library like Jackson or GSON in order to pretty print your output. For an example with Jackson take a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515994/convert-json-string-to-pretty-print-json-output-using-jackson).

Comment: I'd have done it if he had asked about Jackson specifically, but the question wasn't specific.