# Java serialization and deserialization

Tags: java, json, serialization

Please Help me to convert this

```
{"Map1":"{\"t1x\":\"Test1x\",\"t2x\":\"Test2x\",\"t3x\":\"Test3x\"}","Map":"{\"t1\":\"Test1\",\"t2\":\"Test2\",\"t3\":\"Test3\"}"}
```

to

```
{
"Map1":{
"t1":"Test1x",
"t2":"Test2",
"t3":"Test3"
},
"Map":{
"t1":"Test1",
"t2":"Test2",
"t3":"Test3
    }
}
```

Please find below my class

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.webinbox.shared.CommonFunctionality;

public class Test implements Serializable{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = ret();

    System.out.println(json); 
}

    public static String ret() { 
        LinkedHashMap<String,String>map=new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        map.put("t1", "Test1");
        map.put("t2", "Test2");
        map.put("t3", "Test3");

        LinkedHashMap<String,String>map1=new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
        map1.put("t1x", "Test1x");
        map1.put("t2x", "Test2x");
        map1.put("t3x", "Test3x");

        Map<String,LinkedHashMap<String, String>>linkedMap=new HashMap<String,LinkedHashMap<String, String>>();

        linkedMap.put("Map",map);
        linkedMap.put("Map1", map1);
        CommonFunctionality commonFunctionality = new CommonFunctionality();
        JsonObject jsObj=new JsonObject();
        jsObj=commonFunctionality.mapToNestedJson(linkedMap);
        String jsonString=jsObj.toString();
        return jsonString; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Possibly related?: [Convert JSON String to Pretty Print JSON output using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14515994)

Comment: @Pshemo It's more than pretty printing. The string contains JSON objects encoded in strings.

Comment: Looks like you're creating that nested format yourself by calling `commonFunctionality.mapToNestedJson(linkedMap);`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, but based on code example it looks like at start of question we don't have *input*, but *incorrect output* which OP wants to change into *different output* (which linked question hopefully - I am not sure if it is same library - solves).

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonObject mapToNestedJson(Map<String,LinkedHashMap<String, String>>inpMap) {
JsonObject jsRes = new JsonObject();
JsonObject jsResChild = new JsonObject();
    Set<String> keys = inpMap.keySet();
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> values = null;
    Set<String> mapKeys = null;
    for(String key: keys){
        values=inpMap.get(key);
         mapKeys=values.keySet();
         jsResChild=new JsonObject();
        for(String keyValues:mapKeys)
        {jsResChild.addProperty(keyValues,values.get(keyValues));
    }
        jsRes.addProperty(key, jsResChild.toString());
    }

return jsRes;
```

}
}
This is my mapToNestedJson method --- @Robby Cornelissen