# JSON data is displayed in one line in output console of Intellij rest assured

Tags: java, output, testng, rest-assured

When I convert JSON body to String via `response.getBody().asString()` it looses line breakers in JSON response. How can I keep them and display in console output?

If I use simple GET request to get some JSON data, it has beautified view

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.Method;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Demo6_GET_AuthTest
{
    @Test
    public void AuthTest()
    {
       RestAssured.baseURI = "https://test.sideways6.com/api/";
       RequestSpecification httprequest = RestAssured.given();
       Response response = httprequest.request(Method.POST, "auth/login");

       String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();
       System.out.println(responseBody);
    }
}
```

[sample of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WureW.png)

Comment: Please post textual data as, well, textual data, not as an image. We can't copy, paste and debug an image.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/5221149)

Comment: [This might help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38653567)

Comment: Sorry for initial image. Code added.

Comment: If you want it formatted, use `JSON.stringify(jsonData)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing asString will not beautify response,

Try
System.out.println(response.then().log().all());