# need indented spacing in JSON converted string from objectMapper

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, objectmapper

for the given object -

```
{
    "apiRequestType": "add",
    "noOfTIDsRequired": "1",
    "applicationId": "dxvfdv",
    "posId": "1140475",
    "midTidDetails": null
}
```

i get this -

```
"{\"apiRequestType\":\"add\",\"noOfTIDsRequired\":\"1\",\"applicationId\":\"dxvfdv\",\"posId\":\"1140475\",\"midTidDetails\":null}"
```

from -

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(inputMap))
```

but i want this -

```
"{    \"apiRequestType\": \"add\",    \"noOfTIDsRequired\": \"1\",    \"applicationId\": \"dxvfdv\",    \"posId\": \"1140475\",    \"midTidDetails\": null}"
```

can anyone suggest me how can I achieve my expected output using Jackson ObjectMapper.
Or if any other library can be used then please suggest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JSON String to Pretty Print JSON output using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515994/convert-json-string-to-pretty-print-json-output-using-jackson)

Comment: @tgdavies both top 2 answers given in your suggested link gives - "{\n  \"apiRequestType\" : \"add\",\n  \"noOfTIDsRequired\" : \"1\",\n  \"applicationId\" : \"dxvfdv\",\n  \"posId\" : \"1140475\",\n  \"midTidDetails\" : null\n}"

there is an extra \n with every key-value pair. Which is not what i was looking for.

Comment: Why do you want indents but not newlines? I assumed you were trying to make the JSON more human readable.

Comment: bro, if Newlines is what I have wanted, then I won't have put up a new question here on StackOverflow. Google search already suggested to me the link you shared. I exactly want what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Just remove the newlines from the string.

Comment: That is also not easy. in-between '\n' characters need to be replaced with '  ' but ending '\n' characters need to be replaced with ''. And I do not want to customize  encryptino-decryption logic this much.