# Beautify a json file using java

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON file that I downloaded and I don't know its nodes but I want to beautify it using java.

I found many solutions but in my case, I don't know the nodes of my JSON file. So any help please

[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7pvS.png)

[How it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jdIU.png)

Comment: Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457524/json-beautifier-library-for-java

Comment: What are those solutions you tried and didn't work?

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515994/convert-json-string-to-pretty-print-json-output-using-jackson

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON Beautifier Library for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457524/json-beautifier-library-for-java)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I swear I tried all the solutions mentioned above but the problem that in order to build a JSON well-formed file using java(Jackson, Gson, json ...)  you need to know the nodes of your file but I don't because, in my case, this JSON file well be dynamic: every download brings me a new file so it needs to be beautified every time

Comment: @maryemneyli uhm... no you don't? If you read the very first answer to the very first link you've been given you'll notice that it doesn't mention the json's fields anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I swear I tried all the solutions mentioned above but the problem that in order to build a JSON well-formed file using java (Jackson, Gson, json ...) you need to know the nodes of your file but I don't [...]

If you are open to use Jackson, here's a solution that will work:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(SerializationConfig.Feature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(new URL("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json"));
String formattedJson = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonNode);
```

The example above demonstrates how to read a JSON document from a given URL, which may or may not be your case. If it doesn't suit your needs, check the [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) API, as you can read JSON documents from a `String`, from an `InputStream`, from a `File` and others.

The main thing here is: This solution doesn't require you to know the structure of the JSON. As long it's a valid JSON, Jackson will use its tree model to parse it.

---

Alternatively, as you seem to want to parse a Swagger/OpenAPI 2.0 JSON file, you can use the following (check the [documentation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/tree/v1) for details):

```java
Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read("https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json");
String swaggerString = Json.pretty(swagger);
```

Comment: Isn't this identical to the combination of the first two answers in the [twice linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457524/json-beautifier-library-for-java)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I've just checked the links you referred. I agree that one of the solutions I provided is quite similar to one of the existing answers. But you also have to agree that none of those answers mention the usage of `SwaggerParser`. So I don't entirely think this answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: @cassiomolin thank u ! I'm sooo grateful !  u actually saved my career

Comment: @cassiomolin yeah, I reverted that downvote for that reason, even before you commented as I gave it a bit more thought :)